# Detect when all firebase actions are ended

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I compare my device database with another one on Firebase. I do all in a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataInfo.size(); i++) {
   MESSAGE_REFERENCE.child("MyTable_" + myIndex).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                if (!Objects.equals(dataSnapshot.child("_user_id").getValue(), row.get(1).toString())){
                    dataSnapshot.child("_user_id").getRef().setValue(row.get(1).toString()).addOnCompleteListener(t -> {
                        modifications = modifications + 1;
                }

                if (!Objects.equals(dataSnapshot.child("_location").getValue(), row.get(2).toString())) {
                    dataSnapshot.child("_location").getRef().setValue(row.get(2).toString()).addOnCompleteListener(t -> {
                        modifications = modifications + 1;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to post the total of modifications done but the loop is ending before all checks and modifications are done on firebase and allways return for modification a null value.

How can I wait to post result for modifications till all modifications are finally done?

Comment: Since each write operation returns a `Task`, you can use `Tasks.whenAll` to wait for all of them to complete. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958307/upload-multiple-images-and-wait-for-completion-before-returning-android-and-fir and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269110/tasks-await-not-working-for-firebasestorage/54272793#54272793

Comment: can support me with a sample code for my case? the demo links are for storage and I am a hobby programmer.

Comment: The approach how to wait for multiple `Task`s to complete shown in the questions I linked is regardless of the exact API you use ([a `Task` is an Android concept](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks)). I recommend trying to make it work yourself based on the information I provided, and posting a new question showing where you are stuck when calling `Tasks.whenAll` or one of its siblings.